# How to calculate $\iiint x^2$ over $x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2$ and then determine $\iiint x^2$ over $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2\le a^2$ without recalculation?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> How to calculate $\iiint x^2$ over $x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2$ and then determine $\iiint x^2$ over $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2\le a^2$ without recalculating $\iiint x^2$ over $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2\le a^2$?

Let $x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2$ be the sphere $V$. Let $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2\le a^2$ be the sphere $W$.

We can calculate $\iiint_Vx^2$ in spherical coordinates with the following restrictions:
$$
0\le r\le a\\
0\le\theta\le 2\pi\\
0\le\phi\le\pi
$$
so 
$$
\iiint_Vx^2=\frac{4\pi a^5}{15}
$$
But how do I deduce $\iiint_Wx^2$ from that? I suppose I could substitute $u=x-a,v=y-a,w=z-a\implies a=x-u=y-v=z-w$. So I guess:
$$
\iiint_Wx^2=\frac{4\pi (x-u)^5}{15}
$$
but this is not much progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to so this is to note that
$$\int_B x^2\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_B y^2\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_B z^2\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where $B$ is the set $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2\}$. Thererefore
each of these integrals is
$$\frac13\int_B(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
which is really easy to do in spherical polars: it is
$$\frac13\int_0^a r^2(4\pi r^2)\,dr=\frac{4\pi a^5}{15}.$$

Let $B'=\{(x,y,z)\mid(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2\le a^2\}$.
This is the ball of radius $a$ centred at $(a,a,a)$. It's just
a translation of $B$, so
$$\int_{B'}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{B}f(x+a,y+a,z+a)\,dx\,dy\,dz.$$
Then
$$\int_{B'}x^2\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_B (x+a)^2\,dx\,dy\,dz
=\int_B x^2\,dx\,dy\,dz+2a\int_B x\,dx\,dy\,dz
+a^2\int_B \,dx\,dy\,dz.$$
The first you've done. The second is zero, and the last is $a^2$ times
the volume of $B$.

Comment: Is $2a\int_B x\,dx\,dy\,dz$ zero because it's an uneven function over symmetrical range?

Comment: @user123429842 It's odd with respect to $x\mapsto-x$ and $B$ is symmetric under this reflection.